# Python: querying multiple databases using multprocessing pools and queues

Tags: python, database, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm writing an API that lets users run queries across a few hundred databases either singly or multiple at once. When multiple databases are queried, they are accessed in parallel to speed up response time. My semantics: a "q-job" is a query that is executed in one or more databases.

Since it's an internal tool, the number of users is not expected to be large (currently expecting ~5000 queries a day), but some constraints seem logical to me:

1. Only X amount of queries are allowed to run in a DB at the same time
2. Only Y amount of q-jobs are allowed to run at the same time

So far, I can parallelize the querying of the DBs by using `multiprocessing.Pool`, but I'm stuck at queuing q-jobs and limiting the queries in single db's using `multiprocessing.Queue` and the pools (have considered also `multiprocessing.Semaphore`).
Some pseudo-code to illustrate my thinking:

```
# Prepare pool and queues for multiprocessed tasks
process_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = max_processes)
job_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()     # Initialize the queue containing single- and multi-client queries
results_queue = multiprocessing.Queue() # Initialize the queue that holds results

# Query a database
__execute_query_in_db(args):
    # [Open DB connection]
    # [Execute query]
    # [Close DB connection]
    # [Return response]

# Main worker
def __main_worker(w_queue):
    ''' Runs in the background and checks for new entries in the job queue
    '''
    while True:                          # Endlessly check for new items in the queue ...
        conn_strings=w_queue.get(True)   # ...
        __query_worker(conn_strings)     # Run the query 

# Query worker
def __query_worker(conn_strings):
    queries = process_pool.map_async(__execute_query_in_db, conn_strings)   # Run individual DB queries in the pool
   try:
        retArr=queries.get(timeout=1200)    # Execute queries in pool; Timeout after 20 minutes
        # NOTE: We never reach this point!!!
    except:
        logger.error("TS-API Unexpected error: ", sys.exc_info()[0])
        process_pool.terminate()
        results = "Error: %s"%(sys.exc_info()[0])
    else:                   # Wait until all queries have finished
        process_pool.close()
        process_pool.join() 
        logger.debug("Got %s results"%len(retArr))

        ## Ignore empty responses
        results = []
        for result in retArr:
            if result is not None:
                results.extend(result)
    logger.debug("Putting results in results_queue")
    results_queue.put(results)

# Instantiate single-process job pool that monitors new query requests
job_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=1, initializer=__main_worker, initargs=(job_queue,))


# Invoked when an API call is made...
def ExecuteSuperQuery(params=None):
    # [Procure connection string(s)]
    job_queue.put(conn_strings)         # Send connection information to the job queue
    while True:                         # Wait for response to be pushed to results queue
        if not results_queue.empty():   # ...
            return results_queue.get()  # ...
        time.sleep(2)                   # ...

    # [Somehow get the results and show them as a (decorated) JSON string]
```

When I run this type of code and execute a query in a database, the process seems to never go beyond the line marked with "NOTE:". There are no error messages; `queries.get` simply appears to never finish.

I also tried running a single process that instantiated a process pool as necessary to query 1 or more databases each time, but then I got an error about sub processes being unable to run sub processes. Go figure.

I'm asking the community help with the following:

1. Is there a better way to queue q-jobs and keep track of the results?
2. Is there a better way to rate-limit the queries AND the jobs?

Comment: Have you tried shortening you `queries.get` timeout to just a couple of seconds to make sure the `Queue.Empty` exception is raised like it should be? Also, try putting a print statement just before you try to pull something from the queue to make sure execution is getting past the launch of the `__execute_query_in_db function`.

Comment: Thanks; I'm going to try multithreading instead as it simplifies many things and the tasks are not CPU-intensive.